# Visual Studio acting strangely with Emacs keybindings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, resharper, key-bindings

I have bound <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to `Edit.EmacsWordDeleteToEnd` in Visual Studio. This is the only key binding that starts with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, so there are no conflicts.

However, when I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, on some occasions (more often than acceptable) the cursor is only moved across the word to the end of it instead of deleting it. I can't find a good way to reliable reproduce this.

The equivalent happens with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Bkspce</kbd> which I've bound to `Edit.EmacsWordDeleteToStart`, i.e., the cursor sometimes just moves over the word.

I'm using ReSharper 5 if that should matter.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is annoying. I can't vouch for VS2008 but I can't repro that in VS2010 (with Emacs Extension) nor do I recall ever experiencing this issue in VS2005.  I have documented (http://lexicalclosures.blogspot.com/2010/10/emacs-resharper-visual-studio-xkeymacs.html) quite a few conflicts between Emacs Scheme and ReSharper keybindings (and how I resolved them) but yours is one I have not seen before.  

Curious, did you have to manually bind those two Emacs commands?  Were they not already bound in Emacs scheme?  (It might or might not be relevant.)